# How to read Json file in scala, so that all fields will be accessible as key value pairs as in python dictionary

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, playframework, jackson

Trying to read Json file in scala using Jackson but not able to access all elements of resultant map structure

[Use of Jackson to read JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYHR.png)

res41: Object = List(Map(source -> Map(name -> SSN, type -> String), target -> Map(name -> Adhar, type -> String)), Map(source -> Map(name -> America, type -> String), target -> Map(name -> India, type -> String)))

e.g. on above list object not able to iterate

[Error while iterating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T6dQ.png)

**Source JSON structure :**

```
{
  "FeedSource":"TEST",
  "TargetSource":"TEST",
  "SourceEON":"1234",
  "TargetEON":"5678",
  "mappings":[
    {
      "source":{
        "name":"SSN",
        "type":"String"
      },
      "target":{
        "name":"Adhar",
        "type":"String"
      }
    },
    {
      "source":{
        "name":"America",
        "type":"String"
      },
      "target":{
        "name":"India",
        "type":"String"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: try `res41.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]].foreach ...`

Comment: Something like the above would work. The issue is that you have to specify the type with all the nested Maps manually. If you want a more idiomatic solution, try a library like https://github.com/playframework/play-json

Comment: You probably should not read the JSON as a `Map[String, Any]` in the first place if you want to access it's content easily. Create a proper structure to represent the JSON (a `case class`) and parse it into it.

Comment: Hi, @GaëlJ please see this if you have any idea here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471741/how-to-read-json-file-in-scala-using-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-json-jsonma

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper


val json = Source.fromFile("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test_data.json")
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
var jsonMap = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](json.reader())

//convert mapping Obj to MAP
var parsedJson = jsonMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, List[Map[String,Map[String,String]]]]]
```

This certainly works..Thanks :)